# Parser in python to accomplish filtering tasks

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

I am interested, as a bit of an exercise, in writing a little parser in python that can use a set of potential tags, operators, and parentheses so that I can specify things like this:

```
(DP>10) & (LowMQ[0] < 0.05) & (SPV < 0.05)
```

I would need to parse out the tags DP, LowMQ, and SPV as well as the operators and order of operations.  I have seen this done reasonably often in Java, but I have not seen this in python.  Any suggestions on where to start or some example code?

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html

Comment: Using [Pyarsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) and defining a grammar that describes your domain specific language should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since your syntax is a subset of Python's syntax, you could use Python's built-in [`ast.parse`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.parse):

```
>>> import ast, textwrap
>>> src = "(DP>10) & (LowMQ[0] < 0.05) & (SPV < 0.05)"
>>> print '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(ast.dump(ast.parse(src)), width=80))
Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Compare(left=Name(id='DP',
ctx=Load()), ops=[Gt()], comparators=[Num(n=10)]), op=BitAnd(),
right=Compare(left=Subscript(value=Name(id='LowMQ', ctx=Load()),
slice=Index(value=Num(n=0)), ctx=Load()), ops=[Lt()],
comparators=[Num(n=0.050000000000000003)])), op=BitAnd(),
right=Compare(left=Name(id='SPV', ctx=Load()), ops=[Lt()],
comparators=[Num(n=0.050000000000000003)])))])
```

Doesn't solve the general case, but it's very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yapps looks promising. http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/